# Behavior of Inno Setup package during silent reinstall

Tags: windows, installation, inno-setup

I have 2 Inno Setup installation packages. `A` is dependent upon one or more components in `B`. Normally, `A` would silently install `B` flagging just the components it needs installed. Suppose `B` is already installed with user selected components. Now `A` will be installed and needs its usual components from package `B`. How to ensure this? Can I just run the silent install as usual to only additionally install the needed components if they were not already? Will this remove already installed components if they are not selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just run the install silently with the required components.

Inno itself doesn't remove unselected components but the script can perform operations to remove features when a component is not selected.
If you have control over setup B and you've not done this then you don't need to worry.